# How to transfer reaction forces of beam to a weld?

Tags: structural-engineering, structures, structural-analysis

I have modeled a beam as fixed-fixed. The reaction forces are -1494 lb.ft and 761 lb (vertical). There is no horizontal reaction.

[image]

Now I know this beam is welded to another element. I am trying to design the weld for the necessary forces. How do I transfer the reaction forces at the fixed end to the weld? Should I invert the directions of the reactions or should I preserve the same directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I invert the directions of the reactions or should I preserve the same directions?

As long as you keep your directions consistent while solving for the weld forces, it won't matter whether you have them positive or negative.  Referring to my answer to your [first question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/8104/2246) on weld strength, the $f_{xw}, f_{yw}, f_{zw}$ terms are all squared when solving for $f_w$, so directionality doesn't matter so long as you keep it consistent.